# Laravel: Form buttons with names not showing in var_dump

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have 2 buttons with names neither of which show up in a `var_dump($_POST)` or `print_r($_POST)` on a form submit and I'm honestly confused as to why this would be happening. Is it a bug in Laravel or am I missing something? I'm using the latest Laravel version.

**Here is my code:**

```
{{ Form::open( array( 'id' => 'list-form', 'method' => 'POST', 'route' => 'user.admin.list' ) ) }}
    {{ Form::button( 'Show List', array( 'type' => 'submit', 'name' => 'what', 'class' => 'btn btn-success' ) ) }}
    {{ Form::button( 'Email List', array( 'type' => 'submit', 'name' => 'email_list', 'class' => 'btn btn-primary' ) ) }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Thank you for your help!

**edit:**

I've also just tried to do the following:

```
{{ Form::open( array( 'id' => 'list-form', 'method' => 'POST', 'route' => 'user.admin.list' ) ) }}
    <input type="submit" value="Show List" name="show_list">
    <input type="submit" value="Email List" name="email_list">
{{ Form::close() }}
```

But all I see in the output is just the form token and nothing else.

Comment: I just tested the second version of your code locally and it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using Form::button(), but should be using Form::submit(). I just reproduced your form using two routes:

```
Route::any('form', ['as' => 'test', function()
{

    return 
            // This one works
            // 
            Form::open( array( 'id' => 'list-form', 'method' => 'POST', 'route' => 'user.admin.list' ) ) .
            ' <input type="submit" value="Show List" name="show_list">' .
            '<input type="submit" value="Email List" name="email_list">' .
            Form::close() .

            // This one too
            // 
            Form::open( array( 'id' => 'list-form', 'method' => 'POST', 'route' => 'user.admin.list' ) ) .
            Form::submit( 'Show List', array( 'type' => 'submit', 'name' => 'show_list', 'class' => 'btn btn-success' ) ) .
            Form::submit( 'Email List', array( 'type' => 'submit', 'name' => 'email_list', 'class' => 'btn btn-primary' ) ) .
            Form::close() .

            // This one doesn't
            // 
            Form::open( array( 'id' => 'list-form', 'method' => 'POST', 'route' => 'user.admin.list' ) ) .
            Form::button( 'Show List', array( 'type' => 'submit', 'name' => 'show_list', 'class' => 'btn btn-success' ) ) .
            Form::button( 'Email List', array( 'type' => 'submit', 'name' => 'email_list', 'class' => 'btn btn-primary' ) ) .
            Form::close() ;


}]);

Route::any('adminlist', ['as' => 'user.admin.list', function()
{

    dd(Input::all());

}]);
```

In the first 2 you must receive something like:

```
array(2) {
    ["_token"] "TXlMuBczj4OmMEjOlkxusEhpUUZPBTqxQZHch2X2"
    ["email_list"] "Email List"
}
```

Also, you can use $_POST and $_GET in Laravel, but there's a better way:

```
Input::get('email_list');
```

If it doesn't work in your own code, you may have an HTML tag broken or a Javascript conflict. Try to debug it using your full raw HTML code.

Comment: I've tried every imaginable combination just before, but, it's just refusing to show it no matter which of the two buttons you click... I'm questioning my own sanity at this point haha. It may just be something stupid that I've overlooked.

Comment: The problem might be somewhere else, so you first have to isolate it.

Comment: Yep and it works flawlessly, but, yet the same form with the same buttons on my own page doesn't. It only displays the token and neither button you click.

Comment: `The problem might be somewhere else, so you first have to isolate it.` Funny thing is there is nothing else there that would interfere with the form submit in any way, shape or form i.e. there is no other code around just another dropdown I'm not showing currently but is showing in the post data just fine. All that form does is `POST` the data to that route and it does a `var_dump` at that location. Makes no sense, but, I'll keep at it :)

Comment: Get your raw HTML and check it all. Remove things from it until you get it working. You may have broken tags on it.

Comment: Finally managed to isolate it and it was a jquery plugin script that was causing the issue... which makes zero sense. When i commented out the http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/ it finally worked again.

Comment: Cool! Unfortunately this is something that happens way more than we like it to :)

Answer (score -2):

A button is not part of a HTML form and is not send to the server.

Not really sure what you are trying to do here, with two buttons.

If you want a value in it, you will have to add that value to the `$options` array. But then again, what's the point of those multiple buttons?

From the spec:

> The form element that the button is associated with (its form owner).
>   The value of the attribute must be the id attribute of a 
>   element in the same document. If this attribute is not specified, the
>    element must be a descendant of a form element. This
>   attribute enables you to place  elements anywhere within a
>   document, not just as descendants of their  elements.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button

Comment: Not true. It's an input like any other.